# Want to search like that

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I am creating a small real estate website, but need some help in search results. my website is in WordPress.

I want this kind of results:- https://www.affordablehousinggurugram.in

my code is

```html
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
 <div>
  <input value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="<?php echo $unique_id; ?>" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $houzez_local['blog_search']; ?>">
  <button type="submit"></button>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Please give us a proper verbal description of what you want to achieve, do not just point to a different website. (That site might change its behavior at any time in the future, and then your question would lose any context.)

Comment: You need to create a custom post type and then you need to call ajax function on onkeyup event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a trivial problem, but conceptually you would approach it as follows.

In a text input, call a function every time a user enters a value:

```
<input class="someClass" id='someId' name='someName' type='text' onkeyup='getProperties(this.value)' >
```

Where `getProperties` uses ajax and might look something like this:

```
function getProperties(value) {
  $.post(
     "somePHPFile.php", 
      {query: value}, 
      function (data) {
        $(".results").html(data);
      }
  );
}
```

This function sends `value` (the user input) to `somePHPFile.php`, which returns `data` and this `data` is inserted into the HTML element with class `results` (which is the 'live' results as the user types. As a result, `somePHPFile.php` needs to contain your call to your database.